# How to save request in cache asp.net vb,net

Tags: asp.net, sql, request, try-catch, response

My question is : how can i save all request from client side in server side as cache. my point is , if different users sending same request so i do not have to search in sql server ,just return same response to other user ,that will increase the speed of server side , this technique already exist in PHP Apache , im not sure if it is doable in asp.net.

Comment: [Cache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xsbfdd8c(v=vs.100).aspx)?

Comment: oooh yah , i mean cache,thanks for editing . anyway, is it possible to implement my way i just mention.

Answer (score 1):

You can use OutputCache, as described on MSDN (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hdxfb6cy(v=vs.85).aspx )

Comment: yah ,thanks , i found so many ways ,there is a build in cache in .net 4 .just found it .